# Не запускается правильно loc контейнер Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

Изучаю контейнеры, а именно  Autofac. В моем примере у меня есть данные datatable, есть контейнер и два класса, реализующие один интерфейс, по логике я хочу чтобы они запускались одновременно, я их регистрирую в контейнере но, когда класс один, то метод, который в нем, отрабатывает отлично. Когда класса два и в каждом методы разной реализации, то отрабатывает все равно один, вместе почему то они не работают. Наверное где то какой то общий объект они использую. Подскажите как исправить
Код

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using  Autofac;
namespace loc
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

            // Here we add five DataRows.
            table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<CsvOutput>().As<IOutput>();
            builder.RegisterType<Cs2>().As<IOutput>();
            Container = builder.Build();

            WriteDatatoCsv(table);
            WriteDatatoCsv2(table);
            Console.Write("******");

            Console.ReadKey();

        }


       public static void WriteDatatoCsv(DataTable table)
        {
            // Create the scope, resolve your IDateWriter,
            // use it, then dispose of the scope.
            using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var writer = scope.Resolve<IOutput>();
                writer.Write(table);
            }
        }

        public static void WriteDatatoCsv2(DataTable table)
        {
            // Create the scope, resolve your IDateWriter,
            // use it, then dispose of the scope.
            using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var writer2= scope.Resolve<IOutput>();
                writer2.Write(table);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

и два класса

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace loc
{

    public interface IOutput
    {
        void Write(DataTable content);
    }


    class CsvOutput : IOutput
    {
        public void Write(DataTable content)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            IEnumerable<string> columnNames = content.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                Select(column => column.ColumnName);
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", columnNames));
            foreach (DataRow row in content.Rows)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", fields));
            }

            File.WriteAllText(@"d:\test544.csv", sb.ToString());

        }
    }

    class Cs2: IOutput
    {
        public void Write(DataTable content)
        {

            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("<html><body><table>");
            foreach (DataRow r in content.Rows)
            {
                builder.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (var o in r.ItemArray)
                {
                    builder.Append("<td>");
                    builder.Append(o.ToString());
                    builder.Append("</td>");
                }
                builder.Append("</tr>");
            }
            builder.Append("</table></body></html>");
            File.WriteAllText(@"d:\out.html", builder.ToString());

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: [Тыц](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html)

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за ответ, а какой мне приметь декоратор или адаптер? Хочется саму логику понять

Comment: я бы регал декоратор, который бы принимал ваши 2 имплементации и проксировал все вызовы к ним

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо попробую